# Where to check if a class is loaded or not?

Tags: symfony

In HasRoleRepository.php :

```
use \XXX\MyBundle\Model\Role_RT;
use \XXX\MyBundle\Model\Role;

...


public static function toModelClass($hasRoleArray, $RefGroupeRtArray) {
    $roles = array();

    foreach($hasRoleArray as $hasRole) {
        $role = $hasRole->getIdRole()->getId() === 1 ? new Role_RT() : new Role();

    ....
}
```

I have a fatal error : Error: Class 'XXX\MyBundle\Model\Role_RT' not found in \src\XXX\MyBundle\Repository\HasRoleRepository.php line 37

No problem with the Role class, it is just with the Role_RT class.

Same namespace in Role and Role_RT :

```
namespace XXX\MyBundle\Model;
```

I do not understand. this one is not loaded. why ? how ?

Thank you

Comment: I agree with @Splendonia but this may also have something to do with the repository association to its class, meaning there is not one. Can you post the entity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered a bad practice to use _ in Class Names meaning Symfony doesn't detected it (because it's build to prevent bad practices). Change your Model name to RoleRT and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `Splendonia`. If you want to use Symfony (and most generally Composer) you will have to do with the PSR-0 naming conventions.

Please have a look to :

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/